# Am I charged when AWS bucket is free but --request-payer is specified?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

1. AWS bucket is free (no Requester Pays, **not an owner of bucket**)
2. But --request-payer is specified in AWS CLI

Am I charged in this case?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about pricing are off-topic on stack overflow.  See: [Are questions on prices or support of developer services on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274576) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *yes and no*.

From the docs:

> In general, bucket owners pay for all Amazon S3 storage and data transfer costs that are associated with their bucket. However, you can configure a bucket to be a Requester Pays bucket. With Requester Pays buckets, *the requester instead of the bucket owner pays the cost of the request and the data download* from the bucket. **The bucket owner always pays the cost of storing data**.

**TL;DR**

- if you have data in your s3 - you **always** pay
- with *Requester Pays* - the recipient pays for the request & data transfer BUT **you** still pay for the storage

[Using Requester Pays in AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RequesterPaysBuckets.html).

Comment: I am not a bucket owner. I want to download object from not mine S3 storage

Comment: If the request_payer is there, then yes, you pay.